# send email with php and may be configure smtp settings

Tags: php

I am a PHP-newbie. This is my code for sending an email with PHP.

```php
mail("xxxx@gmail.com", "the subject", $message, 
    "From: webmaster@example.com \r\n" 
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

You can find it here in php sandbox:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88e1df4ddf90cdf64d5e04c2c2da4c10dfb801ee

But it doesn' work.

Do I need to setup an SMTP connection? If so, how?

Comment: please if you downvote explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, SMTP is more stable method;
Just use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, and if you would like to run this code in Localhost then you have to Configure SMTP details in PHP.ini. this code will run in Live hosting without any error, you can also design HTML Message with this code.

```
$to_email='xxxx@gmail.com'
$email="webmaster@example.com";
$headers  = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$subject = 'Demo Mail';
$message = 'Your Message'
mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```